# On IBM i, how to run a stored procedure via DB2 command of QShell?

Tags: stored-procedures, ibm-midrange, db2-400

How would you run a stored procedure via DB2 command of QShell, as I need a simple way to unit test a change to a stored procedure?

On IBM i

Started qshell with

QSH

Entered these db2 commands in various formats without success

```
db2 call libraryname.stroredprocedurename('param1value' 'param2value' ?)

db2 call libraryname.stroredprocedurename ('param1value' 'param2value' ?)

db2 call libraryname.stroredprocedurename (param1value  param2value ?)
```

[Only reference source I could find](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/t0007055.html)

Have tried using CLP to call stored proceduresbut there are no CLP examples
[here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/sqlp/rbafyexamplecall.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Squirrel SQL Client http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/ to test all of my SQL.

```
call libraryname.stroredprocedurename('param1value', 'param2value')
```

Note the separator is a comma `,`, and `?` is not a valid parameter marker when called interactively like this.

In addition to the client, you will need a JDBC driver. You can use the JTOpen driver for IBM i found here: http://jt400.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the JDBC client included with jt400.jar.  You can run it from QSH by using the following command.

java -cp /qibm/proddata/os400/jt400/lib/jt400.jar com.ibm.as400.access.jdbcClient.Main jdbc:db2:localhost

The client will also handle stored procedure output parameters as shown by the following example.

> create procedure add1(in inparm int, out outparm int) language sql begin set outparm = inparm +1; end
>   call add1(1,?)
>   Parameter 1 returned 2

Comment: Better might be **-cp /qibm/proddata/os400/jt400/lib/jt400Native.jar** or at least have jt400Native.jar above jt400.jar in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

From the CL command line, or inside a CL program, you can use the `RUNSQL` command to execute an SQL statement.

If you're going to be trying multiple ad hoc SQL statements, you might use the `STRSQL` command.  Personally, I tend to use the SQL window provided as part iNavigator.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the basic syntax

```
db2 "CALL lib.proc ('parmvalue1')"
```

Which resulted in:

DB20000I  THE SQL COMMAND COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY.